# Node pkg-npm doesn't find/add index.html to his node executable file (index.win.exe)

Tags: node.js, npm, exe

I'm trying to build a executable of Node.js using [pkg-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

But it doesn't find/add the index.html that I send to node.
After compile and executed the index-win.exe that was generated I get this message:

> \nodejs_exec\index.html' was not included into executable at
> compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script...

I already tried to add the file in the package.json like this:

```
  "pkg":{

    "scripts": [],
    "assets": [
      "index.html"
    ],
    "targets": [
      "node14-win-x64"
    ]
  },
```

My node **folder** is like this:

```
node_exec
│   index.js
│   package.json    
│   index.html
|   node_modules
```

And this is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const open = require('open');
const path = require('path');


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{ console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)})
```

And the command that I used to create the .exe is:

> pkg index.js